# Fileupload Using Dropzone & Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload multiple files using dropzone but I can't seem to get it to actually upload the file...

I'm getting a "sucsess" respone but the file isn't present.

This is the code that I have:

```
public function post_upload() {

    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'image|max:3000',
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
    }

    $file = Input::file('file');

    $pubpath = public_path();

    $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $directory = $pubpath.'uploads/'.sha1(time());
    $filename = sha1(time().time()).".{$extension}";

    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($directory, $filename);

    if( $upload_success ) {

        return Response::json('success', 200);

    } else {

        return Response::json('error', 400);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys...

I'm being silly... I just wan't specifing the qualifed path, changed it to this and everything is working OK now.

```
$directory = $pubpath.'/uploads/'.sha1(time());
```